# Running Citadel Email on Raspbian Errors

Tags: linux, mail-server, raspbian

I installed the citadel email server onto my raspberry pi.
I can access the gui from my browser, but I can't send or receive emails.
Whenever I send an email, I get the following error back 5 minutes later:

> Subject: Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
>
> A message you sent could not be delivered to some or all of its recipients.
>   The following addresses were undeliverable:
>
> myemail@comcast.net: Connection broken during SMTP conversation

When I try to send an email to the address, I get an error back 5 minutes later saying:

> ```
>  This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.
> ```
>
> Delivery to the following recipients was aborted after 5 minute(s):
>
> - *myemail@citadel.tk*
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns; resqmta-po-07v.sys.comcast.net [96.114.154.166]
>   Received-From-MTA: dns; resomta-po-12v.sys.comcast.net [96.114.154.236]
>   Arrival-Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 22:34:02 +0000
>
> Final-recipient: rfc822; myemail@citadel.tk
>   Action: failed
>   Status: 5.1.1
>   Last-attempt-Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 22:39:08 +0000
>
> Received: from [192.168.1.6] ([*my internet ip*])
>     by resomta-po-12v.sys.comcast.net with comcast
>     id Raa11q00R1XBlzs01aa2Ci; Fri, 08 May 2015 22:34:02 +0000
>   X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.1 cv=D9bJK5hj c=1 sm=1 tr=0
>   a=NqWU7tFnIghBOgBhK6XMcw==:117 a=NqWU7tFnIghBOgBhK6XMcw==:17 >a=C_IRinGWAAAA:8
>   a=GGcpBh7Jt_oA:10 a=FurB0epzNeMA:10 a=IkcTkHD0fZMA:10
>   a=10UFs3TXZvtmx6JxDCUA:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10
>   Message-ID: <554D39D9.3060101@comcast.net>
>   Date: Fri, 08 May 2015 18:34:01 -0400
>   From: *Me* 
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 >Thunderbird/31.6.0
>   MIME-Version: 1.0
>   To: *myemail@citadel.tk*
>   Subject: test
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
>   Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>   DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=comcast.net;
>     s=q20140121; t=1431124442;
>     bh=WY/hcNUSOUDk5CJ+PF8rKNk70vi9Mqo7w16lpbwdlWM=;
>     h=Received:Received:Message-ID:Date:From:MIME-Version:To:Subject:
>      Content-Type;
>     b=JjNnKahyMNU6TzJWtT+TioaalZCVZgpnsdRbVvhfbIHttfyOTq667IIIFBwc+6NKF
>      ytX1PoWhghw65Ejfwv6YldPPLYNzvRfJSDFdLCttUAQWK7KUkOnDi1hsbNzuK00ZGD
>      cIK7/2qaHD4jkkOyl9c9qP7acwxpyGBwOLuMCHz8FrF9K+JU9EPhtQnH//Wt0SYXDD
>      0GRRHF23EfRhFHjXpY6Cm88LqETTSp3DNMcGWLqkGwylPNouPb2PgZr0QTXPgUDdsW
>      OF1pFIt3xhllMxWFKjkNCrr7fieDXAEXDFtBxtEljcLXvhipRZHggzgVDmCwf4Nd8M
>      26tBw5iGgbGXQ==

I am really confused on what I should do to fix this problem.
Any help is appreciated. Thank-You!